# Extracting data from lists of different levels using a function

Tags: r, list, dataframe, extract, hierarchy

Good morning all.

I have a function that uses as a parameter a list to produce different metrics by extracting an element into a df. However, the lists I intend to use are of different hierarchical levels and, therefore, I can't use it on all of them.

I am giving an example (not the real function), below:

```
# the function pulls out a df from a list
df_func <- function(list){
  
  df_temp <- list[[1]]
  
  return(df_temp)  
  
}

data("iris") 

list_a <- list("list_a" = iris, "list_b" = iris,
                     "list_c" = iris, "list_d" = iris)

list_b <- list()
list_b[["list_a"]] <- list_a
list_b[["list_b"]] <- list_a
list_b[["list_c"]] <- list_a
list_b[["list_d"]] <- list_a

df1 <- df_func(list_a) # correct (returns a df)
df2 <- df_func(list_b) # wrong (returns a list of dfs)
```

I know that the problem lies in the fact that to access the correct element from `list_a`  we use `list_a[[1]]` where as to extract the correct element from `list_b` we have to use `list_b[[1]][[1]]`.

The question I have, is how to code this in the function so that R knows where to look for the df I require?

Thank you all for helping a newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a recursive function ?

```
df_func <- function(list){
  tmp <- list[[1]]
  if(class(tmp) == 'list') {
    df_func(tmp)
  } else tmp
}
```

Comment: This is the function (`class`) I was looking for. I am new with R so it didn't cross my mind :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using already available recursive functions i.e. `rapply/rrapply`

```
df_func <- function(listObj) {
     rrapply::rrapply(listObj, classes = "data.frame", how = 'flatten')[[1]]
   }
```

-testing

```
> out1 <- df_func(list_a)
> out2 <- df_func(list_b)
> str(out1)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> str(out2)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: This is a create recursive function. Thank you, I have tried it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of lists (a nested list), you can specify a second parameter (and third, fourth, etc.) in the function to take within the nested list.

```r
df_func <- function(list, list2, index = 1){
    df_temp <- list[[list2]][[index]] # default index = 1
    return(df_temp)  
}

df_func(list_b, 1) # outputs `list_b[[1]][[1]]`
df_func(list_b, 2) # outputs `list_b[[2]][[1]]`
df_func(list_b, 2, 2) # outputs `list_b[[2]][[2]]`
```

It will not work with `list_a` because it is not a nested list (nor the same level of nested list). You will also need more parameters for higher level nested lists.

Here is a more advanced way that is not restricted by any specific levels of nesting:

```r
df_func2 <- function(list, index = 1) {
    l <- paste0("[[",index,"]]", collapse="")
    l2 <- paste0(deparse(substitute(list)),l)
    df_temp <- eval(parse(text=l2))
    return(df_temp)
}

df_func2(list_a) # outputs `list_a[[1]]`
df_func2(list_a, 2) # outputs `list_a[[2]]`
df_func2(list_b, 1) # outputs `list_b[[1]]` (list of data frames)
df_func2(list_b, c(1, 1)) # outputs `list_b[[1]][[1]]`
df_func2(list_b, c(1, 2)) # outputs `list_b[[1]][[2]]`
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I haven't thought of it. However, I would also like to be able to access the elements of `list_a`, which can be done with `list_a[[1]]`. How can I do both with the same function?

Comment: Is there a way to tell R, with an IF statement, what kind of a list it is, i.e. a nested one or not, so to use the appropriate method? Is there a function that gives the levels of a list?

Comment: @DM - To be clear, do you only want the get only and always the first index of the list (multi-layered nested or not) (i.e., always a "1" inside the `[[...]]`), or do you want every index to be selectable/a parameter in the function?

Comment: The index is selectable inside the function with a for loop (I am bad with the use of the `apply` family of functions). So, basically, I iterate through the entire length of the list and extract at each iteration the df that is inside the list and work with it.

Comment: However, I think I found a work around to the problem using an `if` statement which checks the `nrow` of the list at `list[[1]]`. If it returns something it means it is not a nested list. If it returns a `null` then it is a nested list because `nrow` can not be used on a list.

Comment: `df_func <- function(list){if (is.null(nrow(list[[1]]))) {print("NESTED LIST)} else{print("NOT A NESTED LIST")}}`

Comment: @DM - I added an alternative that makes every level index selectable as you requested. I imagine you would want it to do more than just return the list because, well, otherwise, calling the list like `list[[index1]][[index2]]...` or `list$vector1$vector2$...` (where the vectors are the names) is just much more efficient. Since you're working with data frames in lists, you may be interested in using `dplyr::bind_rows`, which can remove a layer of list and combine all data frame within by rows _if they all have the same data structure_ (e.g., `dplyr::bind_rows(list_b, .id="list_names")`).